# Calculate the height of a pyramid

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the height of a pyramid based on the following parameters:

- the base is made of 3 points on the ground where I know the distance between all three i.e I will know the line distance between point 1 & 2 and 1 & 3 as well the line distance between points 2 & 1 and 2 & 3 etc **but I only know the distance of the objects on the ground**
- the base can be any triangular shape as the points can move but I will still know the distance between the three points.

Is there anyway I can work out the height of my pyramid by only knowing the above?

Comment: Imagine that the points on the ground form an equilateral triangle with sides $1$ (it doesn't matter). You can take **any** point above the ground to be the fourth vertex of the pyramid. It could be at height $0.1$, or $40$, or $10000$.

Comment: The thing is the point off the ground could be anywhere, even out side of the base. Would that still work? (irregular triangle pyramid)

Comment: My earlier comment was meant to point out *why* we cannot know the height if we only know the dimensions of the base. That is true even if the apex is not directly above the base, giving us the Leaning Pyramid of Gizah.

Answer (score 1):

Given only the pairwise distance between the three points of the base, we haven't enough information to determine where (or even how far above the base) the vertex would be. Knowing the volume of the pyramid would be enough to determine the height of the pyramid (since we can calculate the area of the base with the information given), but without that, or some other information (*e.g.*: how long the edges from the base to the vertex are), the height could be any positive number.

Comment: By sides lengths I mean I have 3 objects on the ground forming a triangle and I know the distance between each object on the ground. But that is it. These objects can be any length apart. I'll update my question.

Comment: In that case, there's nothing we can do.